# C# representation of hex in byte array

Tags: c#, hex, arrays

I want send hex value through serial port.

The device manual shows that data should be like this:

```
Protocol sent ’ENQ’ ’0’ ’0’ ’3’ ’,’ ’0’ ’0’ ’0’ ’ETX’        
Hexadecimal    05   30   30  33  2C  30  30  30   03
```

The code:

```
    _serial.BaudRate = 9600;
    _serial.Parity = Parity.None;
    _serial.DataBits = 8;
    _serial.StopBits = StopBits.One;
    _serial.Open();

    byte[] bytesToSend = new byte[9] { 05,30, 30, 33 , 2C , 30 , 30 , 30 , 03 }; // This should be represent bytes equivalent to hex value

    _serial.Write(bytesToSend,0,9);
```

i know that i should send this using byte array but i don't know how to represent the hex value in data byte array.

Comment: Just put `0x` in front of your values. Like `0x05` and `0x2C`.

Comment: @Donal The question is not about converting a string to a byte array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the example you provided, your device wants data encoded as ASCII. 0x30 = '0' in ASCII.

And as others have said, you use '0x' to denote hexadecimal values.

for a generic message that begins with ENQ and ends with ETX:

```
ASCIIEncoding asciiEncoding = new ASCIIEncoding();

string msg= "003,000";
byte[] msgBytes = asciiEncoding.GetBytes(msg);

byte[] bytesToSend = new byte[msgBytes.Length +2];
bytesToSend[0] = 0x05;
bytesToSend[bytesToSend.Length -1] = 0x03;
Buffer.BlockCopy(msgBytes, 0, bytesToSend, 1, msgBytes.Length);
```